# Loading 3rd party ads after onload or after firstRender

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

There are tons of questions on SO on how to load iframes after onload so as not to delay the onload event. This question is a little different. We work with an ad network that has given us 2 options to implement their ad tags:

The first one is what they call a synchronous tag. Their advice is that this "should not be hard-coded. Works best if placed in ad server or as passback for another monetization partner.":

```html
<div>
<script src='http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'>
    googletag.pubads().definePassback('/80840/10.example.com_desktop_160x600', [160, 600]).display();
</script>    
</div>
```

The other option is what they call the async tag:

```html
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var html = "javascript:\"<body style='margin: 0;'><script src='http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'>googletag.pubads().set('page_url','"+window.location.href+"').definePassback('/80840/10.example.com_desktop_160x600', [160, 600]).display();<\/script></body>\"";
document.write('<iframe width="160" height="600" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="'+encodeURI(html)+'"></iframe>');
})();
</script>
</div>
```

I am a little embarrassed to say that I don't understand this code. It is using document.write (which I understand isn't good practice) to insert an iFrame whose src is not a URL but some sort of Javascript voodoo. I'm concerned how this ad code will impact page rendering times if it is hard-coded onto the page.

My preference would be to load my custom Javascript file asynchronously, and in my JS, I'd like to do something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Use the ad network's "synchronous" tag
  var html = '<div><script src='http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'>googletag.pubads().definePassback('/80840/10.example.com_desktop_160x600', [160, 600]).display();</script></div>';
  $('#ad-div').append(html);
});
```

But when I do this, no ad renders. Looking at the Network tab to examine requests, I can see that gpt.js is requested but the ad does not render.

So my question is: How do I implement this ad tag without sacrificing page rendering time? I want the users to see the content first, and then the ads can load and take their own sweet time doing so.

Comment: Iframe has his own scope and lives hisown life. iframe is asyncroniously loaded.
Iframe needs just an URL in src="http:///some.url.com/page.html" and it will start load async. independently from your main page. as you can see most of big companies as twitter, facebook and etc are usin iframe to load thir widgets. This will prevent any problems with cross domain loading.

Comment: @Reflective I understand that iFrames load asynchronously given the src attribute. But they do delay the onload event for the page. Also, the way the ad network has their iFrame code, it uses javascript and not a regular src attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Your question has several interesting parts, so let's break it down.

### What's actually going on?

> The first one is what they call a synchronous tag. Their advice is that this "should not be hard-coded. Works best if placed in ad server or as passback for another monetization partner.":

Ad servers (like Google Ads/Doubleclick) typically render their tags asynchronously, which means that the synchronous tag above is appropriate to insert into your ad server because by the time it is delivered to the page, it has been initiated from an asynchronous load. That is, the rest of the page rendering won't be blocked due to the ad tag render.

> The other option is what they call the async tag:

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var html = "javascript:\"<body style='margin: 0;'><script src='http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'>googletag.pubads().set('page_url','"+window.location.href+"').definePassback('/80840/10.example.com_desktop_160x600', [160, 600]).display();<\/script></body>\"";
document.write('<iframe width="160" height="600" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="'+encodeURI(html)+'"></iframe>');
})();
</script>
</div>
```

> I am a little embarrassed to say that I don't understand this code. It is using document.write (which I understand isn't good practice) to insert an iFrame whose src is not a URL but some sort of Javascript voodoo. I'm concerned how this ad code will impact page rendering times if it is hard-coded onto the page.

You are correct that `document.write` typically isn't great practice. In this case, though using `document.write` to generate the iframe is needed because the only other alternative would be to pollute your global namespace with the `html` variable. Let's dive deeper into what the voodoo is actually doing:

```
document.write('<iframe width="160" height="600" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="'+encodeURI(html)+'"></iframe>');
```

The `document.write` is changing the rendered document as it is executed. It writes an `iframe` of specified width and height, with the source of the variable `html`, encoded as a URI. The `html` variable is defined as a String literal:

```
var html = "javascript:\"<body style='margin: 0;'><script src='http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'>googletag.pubads().set('page_url','"+window.location.href+"').definePassback('/80840/10.example.com_desktop_160x600', [160, 600]).display();<\/script></body>\"";
```

It's important that the `html` variable is a String.

The `src` attribute of the iframe instructs the browser to populate the iframe with the resource specified by the URI contained in that attribute. If the `src` attribute used an `http` or `https` scheme, the browser would know to fetch the resources at that URL external URL and inject the responses of that URL in the iframe document. If the `src` attribute were a simple JavaScript expression, the browser would evaluate that expression and inject the results in the iframe:

```
<p>iframe starts</p>
<iframe src="javascript:document.write(1+1)"></iframe>
<p>iframe ends</p>
```

(Note: StackOverflow prevents iframe execution in its snippets, so this won't work here. Copy it to a JSFiddle to see it live.)

The reason the JavaScript above works is that browsers treat string literals returned from the `javascript:` URI scheme *as the contents of the resource*:

```html
<a href="javascript:'foo'">Page with content='foo'</a>
```

So the `html` variable, which is a string, is literally the contents of your iframe. You can see that it includes a `body` tag which itself contains a `script` tag that loads the ad from the ad server.

### Performance Impact

There are three main things to be concerned about: Page rendering time, Execution of scripts dependent on document ready status, and Network connection pool.

1. **Page Rendering time** This is probably not a big deal. Assuming you don't have hundreds of these tags on your page, `document.write` in and of itself shouldn't appreciably slow your CSS calculation and page rendering time. It will probably be slower than hardcoded tags, but it's not likely to be slow enough for a human to notice.
2. **Execution of other scripts** Also not a big deal. The contents of an iframe are loaded in parallel with that of the main page, similar to how a separate browser tab loads separately. It could be a problem if the `src` of the iframe took a long time to load, (see http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/iframe-loading-techniques-performance and http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/03/using-iframes-sparingly/) for more discussions about the impact on `onload` times. However, since we're using a JavaScript string literal as the source of the iframe, it won't appreciably impact the time for the iframe's `onload` to fire, which means the main document's `onload` won't be delayed, which means your own scripts won't be appreciably delayed. (http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/0b18vxkz/ for example).
3. **Network connection pool** This is a concern in the same way as loading any other network resource would be. The more things you load over the wire, the less bandwidth is available for your other page resources.

### Conclusion

All in all, I wouldn't be too concerned about the effect the asynchronous ad tag will have on your page. (Just don't hardcode the synchronous tag by mistake.) If you are really concerned about it, you could potentially delay the loading of the iframe contents even further by wrapping the function calls that create the ad in a timeout. However, that may violate your ad network's terms of service, so be careful about doing something like that.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I'm still unclear on a couple of things. (1.) Why doesn't the synchronous tag (with a regular div and script tag) work when inserted (appended) via jQuery? (2.) Your suggestion to "delay the loading of the iframe contents even further by wrapping the function calls that create the ad in a timeout". Isn't it risky to call document.write in setTimeout -- won't it clear the main page in some cases?

Comment: 1) Best guess is a syntax error. Your posted code is quoted incorrectly, and includes a closing `</script>` tag. (Note that the tag must be escaped to `<\/script>` prevent premature termination of the actual enclosing tag.) 2) I didn't mean to imply to delay the `document.write`, but rather the contents of the iframe. In other words, render the iFrame, then populate the contents of the iframe.

Comment: 1.)I've tried with the correct syntax and it doesn't work. The string I am append()ing can be seen in the Elements panel in dev tools so it's there in the DOM but no ads load. Interestingly, gpt.js gets loaded so it seems like something is executing but instead of gpt.js the URL requested is gpt.js?_123456. That makes me think jQuery's append() is somehow messing with the script being inserted. Any idea what might be going on? (2.) Understood. Thanks.

Comment: Edit: 1.) Not working because gpt.js uses document.write :( So I guess inserting that asynchronously will never work.